# How to get the value within a table cell?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have the following code:

Please look at the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gL2emr8h/3/

I want to get the value of the ID of the selected row. I dont know which function to use to get the value of the first cell from the selected row. At the moment, it is coming out to be undefined.

```
  <table class="table table-striped" style="min-width: 100%;">
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Name1</td>
        <td>Type1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Name2</td>
        <td>Type2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

CSS:

```
tr {
  background: #00eeff;
}

.active {
  background: #ff5500;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
 var selectedHazardId;

  $(function() {

    /* Get all rows from your 'table' but not the first one 
     * that includes headers. */
    var rows = $('tr').not(':first');

    /* Create 'click' event handler for rows */
    rows.on('click', function(e) {

        /* Get current row */
        var row = $(this);
        rows.removeClass('active');
        row.addClass('active');

        selectedHazardId = row.children('td')[0].html();
        console.log(selectedHazardId);
    });
});
```

Comment: Try `.children('td')[0].innerText` instead

Comment: @Quill it is still coming undefined

Comment: When I add `alert(row.children('td')[0].innerText)` after `row.addClass('active')` in your JSFiddle it works fine

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gL2emr8h/3/ yes

Comment: @Quill, ok yes it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulling an item out of a JQuery array by index (e.g. `$("*")[0]`) will give you a DOM object that does not have the `$.html()` function. To use this method you would need to access the textContent property:

```
selectedHazardId = row.children('td')[0].innerHTML;
```

To pull an item out of a jQuery array while keeping it a JQuery object you need to use `$.eq()`.

```
selectedHazardId = row.children('td').eq(0).html();
```

Alternatively, `:eq()` can be used as a selector:

`selectedHazardId = row.children('td:eq(0)').html()`;

Answer (score 1):

Please change `selectedHazardId = row.children('td')[0].html()` to `$(row.children('td')[0]).html()` or `selectedHazardId = $(row.find('td')[0]).html()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `row.children('td')[0]` is a normal DOM item, but `.html` is a jQuery function.

So you could use jQuery's `.html` if you wrap the DOM item in a jQuery function, or you could use one of the native properties that DOM items have.

### jQuery way:

```
var idRow = row.children('td')[0];
selectedHazardId = $(idRow).html();
```

### Native way:

```
var idRow = row.children('td')[0];
selectedHazardId = idRow.innerText // or innerHTML or TextContent
```